# Error while installing packages using yarn or npm, `Request failed \"401 Unauthorized`

Tags: github, npm, yarnpkg

I'm facing an issue while trying to download a package from the GitHub NPM Registry. Whenever I attempt to install the package using the npm registry URL ([https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/[PACKAGE]](https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/%5BPACKAGE%5D)), I encounter a '401 Unauthorized' error.

The exact error message I'm receiving is:

```
error 
>An unexpected error occurred: \
https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/[PACKAGE]: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\".
```

I've already made sure that my GitHub credentials are correctly configured, and I'm logged in to GitHub via the npm CLI using the npm login command. Despite this, I still can't seem to access the package.

Any insights, troubleshooting tips, or solutions to resolve this '401 Unauthorized' error would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you share your `.npmrc`?

Comment: Seems like you are using [GitHub packages](https://github.com/features/packages), did you try logging in? `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After doing a bit of research, I found that you have to enable/check the option of `read:packages` in your Github personal access token .
Because some Packages require a read packages enabled.

Like: [Github Personal Access Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Xxt2.png)

If you have not already setup a Github Personal Access Token, I would recommend you to follow this simple guide: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Post that, you can either

- create a `.npmrc` file at the root level of your project and export your personal access token (or)
- run `npm login` with your user and token

Comment: After adding the personal access token, I had to login using `npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com` with my username and personal access token. Only then did the `yarn` or `npm install` succeeded.